# The 'Collate' method is not supported because the query has switched to client-evaluation

Tags: entity-framework-core, xunit.net, .net-6.0

I am new to .net 6.
I wanted to test with Xunit a method with an explicit collation in a LINQ query .
When I try to test this method , i have this error  : "The 'Collate' method is not supported because the query has switched to client-evaluation. This usually happens when the arguments to the method cannot be translated to server. Rewrite the query to avoid client evaluation of arguments so that method can be translated to server."

My methode :

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DjAggregatePerson>> RecherchePhysiqueAsync(string? nom, string? prenom, string? nomJeuneFille, string? dateNaissance, string? sexe, string? villeNaissance, string? paysNaissance)
    {
        var gda = from m in _LCBFTContext.DjAggregatePeople
                  select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nom))
        {
            if (nom.StartsWith('*') && !nom.EndsWith('*'))
            {
                string customNom = ParametrizedSearch.RemoveAsterix(nom, '*');
                gda = gda.Where(s => EF.Functions.Collate(s.PrimarySurname, "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI").EndsWith(customNom));
            }
            
        return await gda
            .AsNoTracking()
            .OrderByDescending(s => s.PrimarySurname).ThenByDescending(s => s.PrimaryFirstName)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

My test :

```
public async Task Should_get_data()
    {
        var result = await _ppeRepo.RecherchePhysiqueAsync("Dupon",null, null, null, null, null, null);
        result.ShouldNotBeNull();
    }
```

Error :

The 'Collate' method is not supported because the query has switched to client-evaluation. This usually happens when the arguments to the method cannot be translated to server. Rewrite the query to avoid client evaluation of arguments so that method can be translated to server.

Comment: It should work, but maybe you are trying to test with In-Memory database?

Comment: This is what i try to do

Comment: So, this is a problem `In-memory` provider is trying to invoke your `Collate` function. Just do not test this method or test on real Database.